# How can live without inheritance in closure templates in big project?

Tags: javascript, templates, inheritance, google-closure-templates, soy-templates

We use closure library and closure compiler, and we want to use closure templates.

But closure templates haven't got inheritance. That's really a problem for us.

As I understand, the reason why closure templates don't have inheritance, is because templates must be simple, and easy to read.

But how can you live without inheritance in big projects?

For example, we have a template file *button.soy* that generates button with public template `project.createButton` and private templates: `project.createOpenTag_`, `project.createCSSClasses_`, `project.createAttributes_`, `project.createContent_`, `project.createCloseTag_`.

We have JavaScript class `project.Button`, and we have `project.ButtonCircle` (perhaps this separate class `project.ButtonCircle` seems unnecessary, but it's just an example) which extends `project.Button`.

`project.ButtonCircle` needs little changes made in `project.createButton` template.

Of course we can add new functionality to `project.createButton`, but it's a very bad idea, because such approach will create monster templates in the future.

Or we can create public template `project.createCircleButton` in file *button-circle.soy*, call all private templates from `project.createButton` in it, and when we need to 'override' one of these private templates, (for example `project.createCSSClasses_`), we just create new private template in *button-circle.soy* with name `project.createCSSClassesCirbleButton_`.

Yet in this case we need to copy-paste all content from `project.createButton` to `project.createCircleButton`. That's terrible.

Also we tried using Delegate Templates, but it's not suited for inheritance.

What is approach towards this problem?

Comment: inheritance need not be automatic/native to be useful, perhaps you can iterate the source's properties/methods and copy them to a new target instead of letting them naturally percolate; somewhat like javascript extend() tools vs prototype-based inheritance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just write preprocessor that add @extends to soy.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to gather your exact use case but having used soy/closure extensively at my time at Google I sympathize with your puzzlement as they're not my favorite. I agree with @Francois-Richard's general suggestion for keeping common templates very small and composing multiple together. The soy model (and many other JS templating systems I've used frankly) strongly favor composition over inheritance.

**Extension**

If a `CircleButton` is logically and stylistically the same but just with added functionality or styling, then composition will work great.

```
<div class="circle">
  {call .button}
</div>
```

**Parameterization**

If a `CircleButton` is logically the same but stylistically different, why not allow `Button` to be parameterized by shape and reuse the same template?

```
{call .button shape="circle" /}
```

**Composition**

If a `CircleButton` is neither logically nor stylistically the same but merely share some base elements, then extract those to templates/classes and use composition.

```
<div class="circle">
  {call .buttonSharedA /}
  <span>{call .buttonSharedB /}</span>
</div>
```

Soy really doesn't jive as well with the rest of closure vis a vis OO-thinking IMHO, and just requires a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would isolate every common template functions/element and build templates with a factory module. Every templates would be a composition a several small elements and functions.